# When using iFrame, how to enable web scraping (e.g., facebook) on the IFrame with meta data?

Tags: iframe, internationalization, facebook-opengraph, social-media, twitter-card

Given a setup with two websites **A**=http://www.i.am.content and **B**=http://www.i.am.an.envelop.
**A** is internationalized, that is, the user can choose between different languages:
http://www.i.am.content**&lang=en** or http://www.i.am.content**&lang=sw**

Also, **A** is included in **B** via iFrame: `<iframe src=A></iframe>`

Now, users should be able to share **B** via social media (google+, fb, twitter ...). Importantly, the web crawler of the respective social media site should take image&text for the [social media stream](https://moz.com/blog/meta-data-templates-123) from **A**.

However, at least the fb crawler would not look for meta data tags (in the facebook case: Open Graph) in **A**, unless we also specify in **B**: `<meta property="og:url" content=A />`

This means, the link to **A** is hardcoded in **B**'s html.

Our challenge is: How can we transfer meta data, such as the language code chosen by the user, to the link specified in `og:url`? In other words, how to make sure that the social media stream that is automagically created by the web crawlers of the social media providers, receives the link to **A** in the right language/meta settings?

Thanks a lot for any help on this one :)

Also, any help on the analogous problems with Google+ & Schema.org or Twitter cards would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the following:

- **B** gets an extra parameter `A_lang=xy` (if it does not have a fixed language or can convert its own language parameter).
- Change the code of **B** (if that is possible) to include **A** via `<iframe src="A?lang=xy"></iframe>` and the meta tag becomes `<meta property="og:url" content="A?lang=xy" />`.
- **A** can then set the link in the share button to `B?A_lang=xy`. The link to **B** should be in the HTTP Referrer Header, and if that does not work you can always pass it to **A** as an extra parameter in the `iframe` and `meta` tags.

What this requires is of course that you need to modify the page **B** to properly do the language handling for **A**. But in most contexts that should be easy to achieve.